# reference a TypeScript object without 'this' preface

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid in a TypeScript app and in the rowDoubleClicked() function I see that 'this' is now referencing the grid and not 'this' of the class. Thus, inside this function I can't use any of the data from the class b/c 'this' is now pointing to the grid. I tried putting '_this = this' in the class header, but it doesn't work b/c TypeScript makes me reference _this as 'this._this'. So that doesn't work either. Argh. Is there a way to use the class 'this' inside of the rowDoubleClicked() function?

Comment: It would greatly help if you'd add some relevant code to your post.

Answer (score 0):

A you have not provided any code I can guess that the problem is in the way how you assign handlers to the agGrid.

Instead of

```
api.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
```

use arrow functions to keep the scope of this:

```
api.addEventListener(eventName, (args) => handler(args));
```

Same technique applies if you assign event handlers using gridOptions object.

Hope this helps.